# Magento 2 How to Check the Current Product is come from the cart

Tags: magento2, cart, magento2.3.1

Magento 2 current product how to check it is come from the cart edit in observer.

Please refer the cart edit url:

http://127.0.0.1/mage231/checkout/cart/configure/id/26/product_id/1/

Thanks in Advanced

Comment: can you please elaborate your question in detail, what you actually want to do?

Comment: I want to If the product is cumming from the cart edit then i want to apply my custom functionality.so how i check product is normal or coming from cart edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**USE This Code**

```
private $request;

public function __construct(
...
\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
) {
        ...
        $this->request = $request;

  }
```

Use This Condition ......

```
$moduleName = $this->request->getModuleName();// checkout
$controller = $this->request->getControllerName();// cart
$action     = $this->request->getActionName();// configure
$route      = $this->request->getRouteName();// checkout
if (($moduleName == 'checkout') && ($controller == 'cart') && ($action == 'configure') && ($route == 'checkout')) 
{
                  //Your Code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$quote_data = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session')->getQuote();
$result = $quote_data_->getAllVisibleItems();
$itemsIds = array();
foreach ($result as $quote_data_Item) {
    array_push($itemsIds, $quote_data_Item->getProduct()->getId());
}

if(in_array($productId, $itemsIds)){

    echo "in cart";
}
```

Comment: This is a bestway but if more quote data available then foreach loop take a time.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code to check controller and module

```
echo $controllerName = $this->getRequest()->getControllerName();
echo $actionName = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
echo $routeName = $this->getRequest()->getRouteName();
echo $moduleName = $this->getRequest()->getModuleName();
```

You can verify by controller and module name, it would be different than default product view. use `if` condition to do this.

Hope you find your solution

Comment: This is a best way